# How do I stop a blocking task on single threaded systems?

Tags: c++

I'm coding for a single threaded microcontroller and bumped into an issue. How do I stop `Foo bar` from executing?
The use of `<thread>` and `<future>` is not possible on my controller. The command `bar.stop()` is not deterministic. It shall be used as a random user input.

```
class Foo{
  public:
    void start() {
      while(true) {
        if(m_stopped) { return; }
        //do something...
      }
    };

    void stop() {
      m_stopped = true;
    };

  private:
    bool m_stopped = false;
};

int main() {
  Foo bar;

  bar.start();
  bar.stop();

  return 0;
}
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: You should conditionally call `stop()` in `while` as it's usually done in a message loop, and the latter should be `while (!m_stopped) {`

Comment: The `bar.stop()` has to happen within the loop, not after the loop.

Comment: What happens if you use `std::thread` even though the host is single threaded?

Comment: Sidenote: `while(true) { if(m_stopped) { return; }` => `while(!m_stopped) {`

Comment: @TedLyngmo Compiler gives error: <thread> is not supported on this single threaded system

Comment: What version of C++ do you use? Maybe [coroutines](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/coroutines) from C++20 might be an option.

Comment: In the context of a microcontroller you can probably configure one of your I/O pins to trigger an interrupt and write an interrupt handler from which you can change the value of `m_stopped`.  How to do that is going to be very system-dependent though, so you would need to tell us exactly what MCU you're targeting for anyone to be able to tell you how to do that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the system is single-threaded, and there is no preemptive multitasking, then there's nothing you can do from the outside. The system, by its nature, can do exactly and only one thing: the thing its currently doing. There's no way to even *consider* whether the task has been running for too long because all elements devoted to "considering" stuff are being used by the task in question.

Without OS-level preemption or some kind of interrupt, there's no way to cause something to stop from the outside of that function. That function must therefore be written to stop *itself* based on some criteria.

So you have to write `Foo::start` in such a way that it either has the stopping criteria baked in or is given a function pointer to call periodically to tell it if it should stop.

```
using StopFunc = bool(*)(void*);

...

    void start(StopFunc stop_func, void* param) {
      while(true) {
        if(stop_func(param)) { return; }
        //do something...
      }
    };
```

Answer (score 2):

Frankly, you are making this more complicated than necessary by trying to apply concurrency to a single threaded program. There is only one thread in a single threaded application. When you call a blocking method it will block until it returns. The caller cannot unblock it after calling it. The way to return from a `while` loop is to break out of the loop:

```
  while(true) {
    if(some_condition) { return; }
    //do something...
  }
```

You can inject the condition via a callable:

```
template <typename F>
void doSomething(F stop_condition) {
  while(true) {
    if(stop_condition()) { return; }
    //do something...
  }
}
```